# Oddly Ruby behavior

Tags: ruby, struct, least-astonishment

I need to check if a variable is an array, and if not convert it into one before proceed with further processing. So, my code looks like this:

```
class Test < Struct.new(:args)
    def eval
        p "1. #{args}"
        args = (args.instance_of? Array) ? args : [args]
        p "2. #{args}" # woah! [nil]?
        # ...other things, with "args" being an array for sure..or not?!?
    end
end
```

I am quite new to ruby, so perhaps this is not very idiomatic, but to me looks like this code should at least work. Instead, the second time I print the `args` variable, it is `[nil]`.
Notice that if I change the method `eval` slightly:

```
def eval
    p "1. #{args}"
    a = args
    args = (a.instance_of? Array) ? a : [a]
    p "2. #{args}"
end
```

everything works as expected. So, is there something very specific to the Struct class that I don't get it, or something fishy is going on here?
(using ruby 1.9.3-dev on macosx, using rvm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there's a Ruby idiom for what you are trying to do: `[*args]`. `*` in this context is  called the splat operator:

http://raflabs.com/blogs/silence-is-foo/2010/08/07/ruby-idioms-what-is-the-splatunary-operator-useful-for/

If you get passed an array, splat will "flatten" the array into the new one, if you pass a single argument, it will become a one element array.

For the odd behavior: it looks to me like you create a local variable `args` in your `eval` method, which gets initialized to `nil` because it's on the LHS of an assignment. Then the ternary evaluates to false because `args` is not an array and makes an array of the current value, which is still `nil`. If `args` would be an instance variable (`@args`), things would work the way you expect. In other words, while inheriting from the `Struct` will give you `args` and `args=` methods, it won't give you an `@args` instance variable.

Comment: thanks, I'll try the splat operator. Anyway, it's still not clear to me what's going on.. the `args` variable is already instantiated, since I can print it without any problem, and I can reassign it to a local variable (the `a` in the working code). Moreover, I tried using the same code in a top level function, and it works as expected. My suspect is that "args" is defined as some accessors methods that, well, does something that I don't expect :)

Comment: Yes, `args` is an accessor method (as mentioned in the last sentence of my post), so it works inside `p "1. #{args}"`. But then in the next line you define a local variable and when Ruby tries to resolve barewords, it first tries to resolve them as a local variable, not as a method call.

Comment: yep, I got confused by the accessor method that looks like a variable. So that means that, once defined, a property in a struct is unmodifiable? Anyway, I think I resolved by overloading the constructor and simply calling `super([*args])`. Thanks for the lighting-speed answers, btw :)

Comment: It's not immutable, you have `args=`. Your problem was that you "shadowed" the accessor with a local variable. Anyway, glad you got it working :-)